# Reduce vertical space between the caption and a two-column code listing

Tags: captions, listings

Any suggestion about how to reduce the vertical space between the bottom line of the caption and the code?

[image]

Thanks in advance,
Humberto

Here is my current code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}{#1#2#3\hrulefill}
\captionsetup{format=myformat}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{position=bottom,format=myformat}

\lstdefinelanguage{Elixir}{
    alsodigit = {:},
    keywords = {if, and, or, do, end, receive, def, match, defmodule, use, fn, when},
  backgroundcolor=\color{white},
  rulecolor = \color{black},
  backgroundcolor = \color{white},   
  basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
  showtabs = false,
  numbers = left,
  numberstyle = \scriptsize,
  stepnumber = 1,
  showstringspaces = false,
  breaklines=true,
  comment=[l]{\#},
  numbersep=-8pt, 
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  columns=fullflexible,
  extendedchars=true,
  frame=none,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\captionof{lstlisting}{My caption}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{lstlisting}[label=lst:elixir1, language=Elixir]
    def loop({ts_a, ts_b}) do
        state = 
          receive do
            {:msg_a, ts} -> 
                {ts, ts_b}
            {:msg_b, ts} ->  
                {ts_a, ts} 
            {:msg_c, ts} ->
                if ts_b > ts_a do
                    # reaction code
                end
                {0,0}
          end
        loop(state)
    end
\end{lstlisting}
\end{multicols}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update:

Firstly, since `\captionof` is used before `lstlisting` environment, setting `\captionsetup[lstlisting]{position=top, ...}` is more appropriate.

This way, the vertical space between `\hrulefill` and double-columned `lstlisting` environment comes from:

- the skip below caption, which is `\abovecaptionskip` (default value is 10pt), and
- the skip above `multicols` environment, which is `\multicolsep` (default value is 12pt plus 4pt minus 3pt).

By setting

```
\DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}{#1#2#3\hrulefill}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{position=top, skip=-\multicolsep, format=myformat}
```

you get
[image]

You can also use pass a glue expression to `skip` option with the help of `calc` package, in order to (freely) adjust the skip:

```
\usepackage{calc}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}{#1#2#3\hrulefill}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{position=top, skip=-\multicolsep+5pt, format=myformat}
```

[image]

#### Original answer:

This might not be an ideal solution, but seems to work:

```
\DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}{#1#2#3\hrulefill\vspace{-\medskipamount}}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @muzimuzhi Z that solution works for me! 

Comment: @Humberto Hi, some analysis and a more rational solution is added to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update @muzimuzhi. I really appreciate your help. First I was struggling with the default caption position of multicols listings. Later, using 'caption' I solve the position issue, but I still had the extra space between the caption text and the listing. So you solved my problem 

Comment: @Humberto Perhaps you can upvote my answer? :)

Comment: Hi @muzimuzhi Z, I did it, but the system says "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." I'm a new user here 

Comment: I'll do it when I get those 15 points 

Comment: @Humberto Ah, I know. So, welcome to tex.stackexchange.com (again).